# How to obtain the whole disk activities triggered by file systems under linux?

Tags: linux, drivers, hard-disk, ext4

I want to record the disk access activities called by OS. Such data I want to record are received by disk from OS, including disk sector number, request length, arrival time, read or write.

To be specific,the OS is linux with kernel of 3.xxx , the disk file system is ext4. Maybe I need to modify the ext4 driver to record such disk access activities.

The OS is Ubuntu 15.04 32-bit on Intel i686. I am doing a research and want to get the I/O traces of desktops.

Comment: Perhaps using an hypervisor might help. Dou you want to profile or trace file system activity, or raw disk activity?

Comment: I want to track raw disk activity.  And I want to get the logical block number of disk.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that you can get all of this information from the `ext4` driver, because it does not responsible for the disk sectors and other disk geometry, but block device layer sub-sytem in the Linux kernel. I don't see one way to get all information in which you are interesting, because as I see you are in teresting as in low-level stuff and also in high level as r/w operations but look on the [blktrace](http://linux.die.net/man/8/blktrace) util.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear. If you want raw disk I/O profiling (then file system is irrelevant, and you want also to measure swap disk IO) you might have to configure or patch the kernel (I don't know how). Perhaps running Linux thru an hypervisor (like `xen`) might help. Look also into `oprofile`

On the other hand, if you are interested by file system activity, you could use [inotify(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html). Notice that thanks to the [page cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache), file system activity is not the same as raw disk activity.

Answer (score 1):

You need kernel level tracing to achieve that.

There is a large number of tools available to do it with various levels of features, usability and stability including [`sysdig`](http://www.sysdig.org/), [`ftrace`](https://lwn.net/Articles/608497/), [`perf`](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page), [`dtrace4linux`](https://github.com/dtrace4linux/linux), [`ktap`](https://github.com/ktap/ktap), [`systemtap`](https://sourceware.org/systemtap/) and others.

You might start with [tpoint](https://github.com/brendangregg/perf-tools/blob/master/system/tpoint) which, being based on `ftrace`, shouldn't need anything to be installed (outside the script itself), eg:

```
# tpoint -H ext4:ext4_da_write_end
```

To go further, I would suggest investigating with `systemtap`.